# Are there any resources to learn Solresol available in English?

Tags: resource-request

I've been interested in learning Solresol, as the idea of it intrigues me. But I haven't been able to find anything in English to learn it from (the original works on the language are in French, which I don't know).

I checked out [sidosi.org](https://www.sidosi.org/resources), and it shows a couple of links to an English translation of the original grammar of Solresol, but [one redirects back to the sidosi.org homepage](http://mozai.com/writing/not_mine/solresol/sorsoeng.htm), and [one leads to a message saying the site has been retired from service](https://webspace.utexas.edu/bighamds/LIN312/Files/SolReSol.pdf). Other resources are also linked, and also turn out to be missing.

So are there any resources (preferably online) to learn Solresol from English?

Comment: @as4s4hetic If you have an answer, please post it in the 'answer' section below. Thanks.

Comment: sidosi.org must have a bug, but they also have another link if you click the `[+]` and the link that appears (probably as a mirror).

Answer (score 4):

You can find many articles at [SiDoSi (sidosi.org)'s resources page](http://sidosi.org/resources) or at this [tutorial on blogspot](http://solresol.blogspot.com/2012/07/learning-solresol-lesson-1-introduction.html?m=1). Also, I'd recommend a translation of "The second major book about Solresol, written by the other major contributor to Solresol, Boleslas Gajewski," also at sidosi.org [over here](https://i.sidosi.org/resources/grammar-of-solresol/grammar-of-solresol.html).

---

Note that [SiDoSi (sidosi.org)'s resources page](http://sidosi.org/resources) has an error that requires you to click the `[+]` and then the link that appears because the direct links don't work and redirect you. Else see the [beta](https://www.sidosi.org/resources-beta) version, without broken links.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I missed this question. Many of the main links on [Sidosi's Resources page](https://www.sidosi.org/resources) are unreliable, but you can view the archived copies by expanding the info box for a resource (click the + to the left of the title), or clicking the "Show/Hide All" link near the top of the page.

Alternatively, there is a [beta Resources page](https://www.sidosi.org/resources-beta) that hasn't been widely publicized yet, and it presents the resources in a much better format than before, with no broken links. It's only considered beta because this new version was coded from scratch, and there are a ton of new resources due to be added.

There are still many original French documents that haven't been translated to English (Sudre's book, for example), so the Solresol community as a whole shares in your struggle for English resources. Basically, there still aren't any good English resources for learning Solresol, but hopefully the ones that are available help.